# When I run Keycloak it shows these this log messages, How to reslove this?

Tags: authentication, docker-compose, keycloak

I am trying to run Keycloak(image: 22.0.5) using my docker-compose file, I am using external database(Postgres), When I build the logs show:

**Logs:**

`2023-10-31 11:39:16,126 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main) Hostname settings: Base URL: <unset>, Hostname: localhost, Strict HTTPS: false, Path: <request>, Strict BackChannel: false, Admin URL: <unset>, Admin: <request>, Port: -1, Proxied: false`

`2023-10-31 11:39:18,053 WARN  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000569: Unable to persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state enabled`

**Docker-Compose service:**

```
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.5
    command:
      - start-dev
    environment:
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_URL_HOST: db
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_USERNAME: postgres
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: postgres
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KC_METRICS_ENABLED: true
      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: ********
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ********
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - local-keycloak
```

How to resolve this

Comment: Try to add these two variables:
KC_HTTPS_HOST=localhost
KC_HTTPS_PORT=8080
and maybe:
KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true

or just delete:
KC_HOSTNAME: localhost

Comment: @Djordje Tried adding  KC_HTTPS_HOST: localhost KC_HTTPS_PORT: 8080 KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true, these doesn't make any difference. It still says,2023-10-31 12:49:17,587 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main) Hostname settings: Base URL: <unset>, Hostname: <request>, Strict HTTPS: false, Path: <request>, Strict BackChannel: false, Admin URL: <unset>, Admin: <request>, Port: -1, Proxied: false

Comment: @Djordje 2023-10-31 12:49:18,782 WARN  [io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources] (main) Datasource <default> enables XA but transaction recovery is not enabled. Please enable transaction recovery by setting quarkus.transaction-manager.enable-recovery=true, otherwise data may be lost if the application is terminated abruptly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no serious problems indicated by the log messages you shared. To further guarantee your setup runs smoothly, though:

1. Keycloak depends on your PostgreSQL database container, `db`, so make sure it's accessible and available. Verify that it is operational and set up properly.
2. Look over the hostname setup. For local development, the Keycloak hostname's `localhost` configuration might work. Nevertheless, you should think about changing the `KC_HOSTNAME` environment variable to your server's IP address or domain name if you plan to use Keycloak from different computers.
3. Regarding the internal caching mechanisms that Keycloak uses, the warning regarding Infinispan internal caches is usually not a serious issue and can be disregarded.
4. Verify that all required ports are open and reachable, such as `port 8443` for Keycloak and `port 5432` (PostgreSQL) for the database.
5. Check that the administrator access you are expecting to be granted to Keycloak is granted to you and that your credentials (`KEYCLOAK_ADMIN` and `KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD`) are correct.

You ought to be able to properly use Keycloak with your external PostgreSQL database if you take care of these issues and thoroughly review your configuration. If you run into specific problems or error messages, do let us know more information so that we can help you further.

Comment: Thanks, This was helpful. I had this another issue, it would be helpful if you can guide me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77407069/keycloak-in-production.

Comment: sure i'll have a look at it, kindly upvote my above answer if it was helpful to you