# Keycloak in production

Tags: docker-compose, keycloak

I am trying to launch Keycloak in production mode on server and have setup docker-compose keycloak config the following way, it says:

```
mycompanyauth-keycloak-1  | 2023-11-02 04:38:28,055 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (production) mode
mycompanyauth-keycloak-1  | 2023-11-02 04:38:28,055 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Key material not provided to setup HTTPS. Please configure your keys/certificates or start the server in development mode.
```

```
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.5

    command:
      - start --transaction-xa-enabled=false
    environment:
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_URL_HOST: db
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_USERNAME: postgres
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: postgres
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: "true"
      KC_METRICS_ENABLED: "true"
      KC_HOSTNAME: auth.mycompany.com
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KEYCLOAK_JDBC_PARAMS: sslmode=enable&connectTimeout=40000
      KEYCLOAK_EXTRA_ARGS: "-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.scripts=enabled"
      KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE: /opt/keycloak/certs/fullchain.pem
      KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE: /opt/keycloak/certs/privkey.pem
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./etc/letsencrypt/live/auth.mycompany.com/fullchain.pem:/opt/keycloak/certs/fullchain.pem
      - ./etc/letsencrypt/live/auth.mycompany.com/privkey.pem:/opt/keycloak/certs/privkey.pem
    networks:
      - local-keycloak
```

can anyone help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Usually container runs with the keycloak user. But most of the time these certificate files are readable by root only. So you end up with keycloak having insufficient permissions to read the key files.

Can you check the permissions for your certificate files? and change the permissions if required

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak is giving you an error that has to do with how the SSL certificate is configured. Although it can't locate the certificate files, Keycloak is expecting SSL certificates for HTTPS. Make sure the files for your SSL certificate are on your server and that the paths to them in the Docker Compose volume settings are accurate in order to fix issue. Furthermore, confirm that the certificate files are authorised for reading by the Keycloak container. By executing a shell within the container and looking at the file locations and permissions, you may verify this. Additionally, it is crucial to verify that the certificate files are valid for usage with the hostname `auth.mycompany.com` in a production environment and that they are in the correct PEM format.

Comment: How did you get solved this. I am facing same issue.